# How do free electrons move in a solid?

Tags: solid-state-physics, electric-current, semiconductor-physics, conductors, electronic-band-theory

Can anyone describe how free electrons move in a solid, like when an electron moves into conduction band does it permanently goes out or still exist around the atom.

When we say electrons it is being refered to electrons in conduction band right?

Comment: The atom never becomes positive.Think it as a cloud of negative charge surrounding all the atoms. The electrons acquires energy and becomes a part of this cloud

Answer (score 1):

The [band theory of solids,](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/Solids/band.html) a quantum mechanical theory, fits the data very well.

[image: bandtheory]

Quantum mechanics has [orbitals for electrons](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/Chemical/eleorb.html) in a potential, whether atoms, molecules, or solids. Probability loci, where it is most probable to find the electron.

In the case of solids, the electrons in the conduction band see a collective potential from the solid and their orbitals have very small differences in energy levels. If  the solid is an insulator   the conduction band is not occupied unless special conditions are met. If a conductor, there are a lot of electrons in the conduction band.

> when an electron moves into conduction band does it permanently goes out or still exist around the atom.

In a conductor the electrons in the conduction band are shared by all the atoms of the solid, from the time of construction of the solid. They do not go from the valence band to the conduction after the lattice is formed.  That is why the electrons are sometimes thought as "free". In conductors the bindng energy in the conduction band  is small. They have a probability of being anywhere in the conductor, no longer tied to the lattice of the solid.