# Persistent confusion about "electrons" in electricity

Tags: electricity

These two statements seems contrasting:

> **Electrons** in the outermost shell are loosely held to the nucleus.

> In a metal **electrons move freely in all directions.**

I am very confused as to its position.

How can it move freely when there is a complex system of protons, other electrons etc. around it?

Please explain.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: please see this answer of mine to a similar question https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/561151/how-do-free-electrons-move-in-a-solid/561191#561191

Answer (score 1):

See

https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/6513/why-are-there-free-electrons-in-a-metal

or

https://www.thoughtco.com/metallic-bond-definition-properties-and-examples-4117948.

There is a difference between single atoms and metal. For single atoms the first statement holds. For metals the key word is metallic bonding. Simplified you can say in metallic bonding every metal atom contributes at least one electron to something like an "electron sea". Those electrons can move freely.